# Jenkins remote api error 404

Tags: linux, api, jenkins

I am trying to update remote `jenkins` `config.xml` file but i am having issue, I am sure username and password are correct and path of file also correct because same thing is working in other server but with newer version of jenkin `1.514`. I have having issue with `1.501` version, Even i have disabled `cross-site request forgery (CSRF)` any idea how to make it work if there is any work around?

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=spatel --http-password=secret --post-file=config.xml --no-check-certificate http://jenkin.example.com/jenkin/jobs/Sched_M_Builds2Test/config.xml
--2013-05-23 15:54:22--  http://jenkin.example.com/jenkin/jobs/Sched_M_Builds2Test/config.xml
Resolving hudson.outcome.com... 10.101.100.60
Connecting to hudson.outcome.com|10.101.100.60|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-05-23 15:54:22 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: 404 suggests the URL you're accessing does not exist. Considering how jenkin*s* is usually written have you tried the URL `http://jenkin.example.com/jenkins/jobs/Sched_M_Builds2Test/config.xml`?

Comment: But if i enable CSRF, I am getting `ERROR 403: Forbidden.` error

Comment: Do you know how to `POST` using CSRF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably talking about software called Jenkins - http://jenkins-ci.org/ but your link points at `jenkin`.

404 means not found so please make sure that you have right URL.

Comment: I guess you are right, when i run `lynx http://localhost:8080` on terminal i got 404 page but after few second it got refresh and prompt for login, do you know how to fix that because of it i am not able to access API

Comment: I found the problem its path `job` not `jobs` what a stupid problem